# Im trying to swap between 2 divs every Sunday

Tags: html, automation, hide, show, swap

I have 2 divs and I am trying to swap them around automatically every Sunday at 11:59. My divs:

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Title</title>
        <script>
            function changeDiv(){
                var d = new Date();
                if (d.getDay == 0 && d.getHours == 11 && d.getMinutes == 59) {
                    if (document.getElementById("cDisp").innerHTML == "Div2") {
                        document.getElementById("cDisp").innerHTML = "Div1";
                        document.getElementById("Div1").style.display = null;
                        document.getElementById("Div2").style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("cDisp").innerHTML = "Div2";
                        document.getElementById("Div1").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("Div2").style.display = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <code id="cDisp">Div1</code>
        <br />
        <button name="changeDiV" onclick="changeDiv()">Change DIV</button>
        <div style="color: rgb(244,100,100);" id="Div1">
            <p>asdasdasdasda (Div1)</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none; color: rgb(22,232,123);" id="Div2">
            <p>1231231231313132 (Div2)</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This brother will be the right answer. The first code I have given you will only change the name of the div container but do not swap two divs to which one will display.

Give it a try by running this snippet (in this example it changes the div to display and indicate which div is displayed.

```js
function changeDiv(){
    if (document.getElementById("cDisp").innerHTML == "Div2") {
        document.getElementById("cDisp").innerHTML = "Div1";
        document.getElementById("Div1").style.display = null;
        document.getElementById("Div2").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("cDisp").innerHTML = "Div2";
        document.getElementById("Div1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("Div2").style.display = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <code id="cDisp">Div1</code>
        <br />
        <button name="changeDiV" onclick="changeDiv()">Change DIV</button>
        <div style="color: rgb(244,100,100);" id="Div1">
            <p>asdasdasdasda (Div1)</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none; color: rgb(22,232,123);" id="Div2">
            <p>1231231231313132 (Div2)</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have my divs and each one has its own class, the class's are Div1 and Div2, what part of the script above do I need to change please? I tried changing both the divOne and divtwo aswell as then changing where you have put class but neither worked provided I did it correctly?

Comment: does the div tags goes something like this `"<div id="exchangeableDIV" class="Div1">` or `<div id="exchangeableDIV" class="Div2">`? If not, perhaps it's what lacks in the code... try adding an ID of your choice (change "exchangeableDIV" to any name) and "divOne" and "divTwo" above as Div1 and Div2

Comment: Please do send a comment after doing so I can keep track.

Comment: <pre><code>                            <div id="exchangeableDIV" class="divOne"> Green </div>
       <div id="exchangeableDIV" class="divtwo"> Blue </div>
<script>    
var d = new Date();
var desiredDay = 0;
if (d.getDay = desiredDay && d.getHours = 11 && d.getMinutes = 59) {
    if (document.getElementById("exchangeableDIV").getAttribute("class") = "divOne"){
        document.getElementById("exchangeableDIV").setAttribute("class") = "divtwo";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("exchangeableDIV").setAttribute("class") = "divtwo";
    }
}
</script></code></pre>

Comment: Sorry for the poor formating, thats what is in my HTML file and yet it is still not working, does that look correct to you? thanks

Comment: I also apologize, condition statement's equals must be doubled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141311/discussion-between-jimwel-anobong-and-user1203306).